# How to convert an int value into a long value in Java?

Tags: java

I am having two integer values and I want to return the difference of those two values as a long in java.

Is it possible?

Comment: You title and question contradict each other.

Comment: You can freely return an int from a long-returning method. Why don't you just try it? And if the most obvious thing fails, then please post your failed code.

Comment: Your question title is contradicting with the description.
If your description is correct - then look at the answer from @juergen d, which is correct.
If you need something else make sure to edit the question correctly

Answer (score 10):

You can just assign the result to a long:

```
long result = intval2 - intval1;
```

Comment: Why - what error are you getting?

Comment: `its not working` That doesn't tell us anything. Can you provide an example of when its not working, what you expected and what you get?

Comment: To change the retun type to integer

Comment: @user1741201.. What exactly you want. You need to be first sure and explain properly. You seem confused.

Comment: In all this confusion, why not add a nitpick: `(long)` is neither a **cast** nor **implicit** :) The same syntax is used for both *conversions* and *casts* in Java, as well as in C, and `(long) intval2` is a **conversion expression** of the *promoting* type, where the explicit operator is not needed.

Comment: No conversion required: just an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
long difference = (long) i1 - i2;
```

if you need the absolute difference

```
long difference = Math.abs((long) i1 - i2);
```

e.g.

```
int i1 = 2000000000;
int i2 = -2000000000;
long difference = Math.abs((long) i1 - i2);
System.out.printf("%,d%n", difference);
```

prints

```
4,000,000,000
```

---

The reason you may need to cast to `long` is to avoid overflows.  The largest difference between two int values is between the maximum and the minimum but if you do

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

prints

```
-1
```

due to an overflow, whereas with a cast you get

```
System.out.println((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

prints

```
4294967295
```

Comment: @EJP with out casting an `int - int` is an `int` which would overflow.

Comment: Overflow how? Both operands are ints, so the difference is an int as well. All it needs is sign extension, which it gets automatically on promotion. Where's the overflow?

Comment: The difference between Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE is around 4 bn (like my example) This overflows to -1 as an int. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public Long difference(Integer i1, Integer i2){
   return new Long(i1-i2);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an `Integer` or `Long` when an `int` or `long` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val1=10;

int val2=6;

long val3 = (long) val1 - val2;
```

Comment: He/She's asking about difference. Where are counting difference?

Comment: Aren't they all "with boxing", because you are using the class versions `Integer`/`Long`

Comment: Oh..The question title and the question body contradict each other.

Comment: bean.setIntegerProperty(LongValue1-longValue2)- here set IntegerProperty is an integer and LongValue is long property.

Comment: @user1741201 You have just asked the opposite in the post.

Comment: @Arun pls edit your answer so that I can remove downvote.

Comment: Integer terrible = (int)l; is sufficient for the last case.

Comment: @Suzan Cioc . Hey..i have updated my answer as per question requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have big Integers, you can use `Integer.longValue()` on both and simply subtract those values.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is rocket science. If i1 and i2 are Integers or ints:

```
return i1-i2;
```

Java 1.5+ required. But no casts or conversions.

Hard, i.e. impossible, to believe you even tried anything.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, convert to long and subtract:

```
public long diff(int i1, int i2) {
     return ((long) i1) - i2;
}
```

Autoboxing takes care of wrapping/unwrapping as required

Comment: There is no boxing here is there? Just simple casts.

Comment: There would be if the return value is stored in a wrapper variable or the parameters would be wrapper instances. Maybe my sentence abount autoboxing is a little misleading. I added that sentence because of the questions *title* (it talks about capital Integer/Long).

Comment: I see, yeah the question title didn't match the question. It's caused havok!

Comment: No cast/conversion required either.

Comment: @ejp If you omit the cast, you will get wrong result for e.g. i1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, i2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE (try it out, you'll see the difference). The cast forces the expression to be evaluated with long precision. The brackets *could* be omitted, but I prefer it with brackets because its obvious then what is casted without needing to know the exact prededence of the cast operator.